# How to find maximum value per group for all rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql, select, max, window-functions

How to get the maximum value per group and get all rows of table?

```sql
create table out_pumptable(
name varchar(255),
    value double precision,
    anothercolumn varchar(255)
)

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 1', 8000.0, 'Something1');

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 1', 10000.0, 'Something2');

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 1', 10000.0, 'Something3');

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 2', 3043, 'Something4');

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 2',4594, 'Something5');

insert into out_pumptable
values ('Pump 2', 6165, 'Something6');
```

Required output

```
    name    value   anothercolumn max
    Pump 1  8000.0  Something1    10000.0
    Pump 1  10000.0 Something2    10000.0
    Pump 1  10000.0 Something3    10000.0
    Pump 2  3043.0  Something4    6165.0 
    Pump 2  4594.0  Something5    6165.0
    Pump 2  6165.0  Something6    6165.0
```

My attempt

```sql
select name, value 
from( select name, value, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY name ORDER BY value desc) as rn
from out_pumptable ) as a
where rn = 1
```

Comment: Tag only the database that you use.

Comment: Use a windowed aggregate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `MAX()` window function:

```
SELECT *, 
       MAX(value) OVER (PARTITION BY name) "max"
FROM out_pumptable;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=c003351e1bb23772416b6b7cbba8febf).